# WP_Query for CPT with filter by another WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, customization

I'm working on a project have 2 CPTs:

- **Projects**
- **Units**

Every **Unit** has a meta value containining the `id` of **Project**
Every **Project** is assigned a custom taxonomy named **Regions**

Now I need get all **Units** in a specific **Region**

I think I must `WP_Query` to get all **Projects** in a **Region**
then use the array of **Projects** `ids` to find **Units** by another `WP_Query`. I've tried a few times but was unable to solve it. How can I get all **Units** in a **Region**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in your approach. If you post your code will be better, but something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'region',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $region, //set your region
        ),
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop of Projects by Region
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    $projectsid = array();
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $projectsid[] = get_the_ID();
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'unit',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => $keyname, //set the key name which store ID
                'value'     => $projectsid,
                'compare'   => 'IN',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
            ),
        ),
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop of units in project per region
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            //do something

        }

    } else {

        //No units for projects in this region

    }

} else {

    //No projects in this region

}

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your awesome answer :)

Comment: @Kika if this answer solved your issue, please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. It will go green. Please read [what you should do when someone answers your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)